# Unity with FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to set a FileSystemWatcher in unity where I need to change the color of an object when a file is updated.

There is no error on the code, but the result is not taking action. I am able to change the color of the object if I used the void Start(). but I need to run the code only if a change happened in the desired location.

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;

public class ObjColorScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color myColor;
    public MeshRenderer myRenderer;


    // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
    {
        string path = @"B:\";
        MonitorDirectory(path);


        ///// New Added
        var fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        fileSystemWatcher.Path = @"B:\";
        fileSystemWatcher.Changed += FileSystemWatcher_Changed;
        fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }


    ///// New Added
     void FileSystemWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        myRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        myRenderer.material.color = Color.green;
    }




    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //myRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        //myRenderer.material.color = Color.green;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I wanted to call a method on change and it wouldn’t be called. I believe this has something to do with events being called outside the Unity run loop?

Anyway for me it helped to set a bool flag on change and call the actual method from within `Update()`:

```
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;

public class MyFileWatcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private string path;
    [SerializeField] private string file;
    private bool changed;
    private FileSystemWatcher watcher;


    private void OnEnable()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(path, file)))
        {
            return;
        }

        watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = path;
        watcher.Filter = file;

        // Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
        // the renaming of files or directories.
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;

        // Add event handlers
        watcher.Changed += OnChanged;

        // Begin watching
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }


    private void OnDisable()
    {
        if(watcher != null)
        {
            watcher.Changed -= OnChanged;
            watcher.Dispose();
        }
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        if (changed)
        {
            // Do something here…
            changed = false;
        }
    }


    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        changed = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I can confirm, the Changed events (Renamed, Move, Deleted, etc.) are called on another thread, and this will lead to no errors since Unity only operates on the main thread.